# LMDB data for multi-label classification and layers definition in caffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, multilabel-classification

I am a beginner in caffe framework and I would like to implement the training of a CNN model with multi-label data.
I know how to create a lmdb data in python like this [example](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) but I couldn't find any complete tutorial of how to define the labels when an image has 2 or more labels.

Do you know if there is a complete and clear example of how to create such data and how to define the accuracy and loss layers in the prototxt files.

Comment: @HarshWardhan I have seen that post and the question is about how to create a data using the `create_imagenet.sh` code in caffe whereas I am asking how to create a customized data using python like the example in the link that I have mentioned in my question